# Selected image is not coming in Detail View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView in a viewcontroller. I named this viewController as TabViewController. Now in that collectionView I have some images. Now when I am tapping on the cells it is pushing to another viewController named as DetailViewController. In DetailViewController I have an imageView. I want to show the selected image in TabViewController in the imageView of DetailViewController.

But no images are coming. Can any one show me where I am wrong.

This is the code that I have done.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

if (collectionView.tag == 6) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailController" sender:self];
        _lastSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:_myPatternString];

    }

}
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    DetailViewController *detailObject = (DetailViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;

    detailObject.selectedImageInPreviousVC = _lastSelectedImage;

}
```

and in DetailViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
    _myImageView.image = _selectedImageInPreviousVC;

}
```

Comment: Debug and check code after this point `detailObject.selectedImageInPreviousVC = _lastSelectedImage;` if the image is assigned

Comment: in selectedImageInPreviousVC, nil coming. :( @GaneshSomani

Comment: What about `detailObject` just above it. Also check that `_lastSelectedImage` is not nil while debugging.

Comment: Only one image is passing everytime I tap on any cell. :( GaneshSomani

Answer (score 1):

You could directly sent the image in `performSegueWithIdentifier.`

Use something like this:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (collectionView.tag == 6) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailController" sender:[UIImage imageNamed:_myPatternString]];
    }
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    DetailViewController *detailObject = (DetailViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;

    detailObject.selectedImageInPreviousVC = sender;
}
```

Also make sure that `detailObject.selectedImageInPreviousVC` is not a `weak` `property`.

Comment: I REALLY don't think you should be sending and UIImage as sender.

Comment: From the code is posted, the sender does not make any sense altogether, cause he could also just use `detailObject.selectedImageInPreviousVC =[UIImage imageNamed:_myPatternString] `. I suggested that, so that he could see if the problem comes from saving the image as a property or something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (collectionView.tag == 6) {

// Perform segue need to be called after _lastSelectedImage has been set

        _lastSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:_myPatternString];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailController" sender:self]; 
    }

}
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    DetailViewController *detailObject = [segue destinationViewController];
    detailObject.selectedImageInPreviousVC = _lastSelectedImage;
}
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, please add some clarification why it's working and why his wasn't.

Comment: I guess _lastSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:_myPatternString];
this should be called before the function call.

Comment: I know why it's correct. I just want you to edit your answer to explain it. So 1) the person asking the question understands what he did wrong. 2) It will be helpful in the future for anyone stumbling over this answer.

Comment: Only one image is passing everytime. :( @Kaey

Comment: You are setting the _lastSelectedImage inside an ifcase, hence the value is always same.

Comment: I am using if case just because there are 2 collectionViews. @Kaey